# In MySQL, can I select all columns from one table and one from another?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have a simple `"SELECT * FROM foo"` query. I would like to `JOIN` table 'bar', but:

1. I only want one column from `bar`
2. I specifically DON'T want the `id` column from `bar`, because it will conflict with the `id` column from `foo`

I know that I could use `as` statements to avoid name conflicts, but I don't want to complicate things. Is there a way to write this query without naming every column I want from `foo`?

In other words, can I say 'give me all the columns from `foo` and just this one column from `bar`?

### Update: Why this is bad practice

Folks have pointed out that `"SELECT *"` is generally bad practice, because:

- It returns unnecessary data. That could, now or in the future, include something large, like a BLOB data column.
- If the database schema changes, the query may not return one of the expected columns. If the column is named explicitly in the query, there will be an error; if not, it may fail silently (insert a blank where a title should go, for example).

Comment: Select * is fine for something quick-and-dirty, but if you're doing anything clever with the results, your code is likely to break when the table changes structure. Identifying the columns you want in the order you want them is a good way to prevent future headaches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.whatever FROM ...
```

Note, however, that this is considered bad practice. You should always name all columns in the order you expect them to.

Comment: Bad practice as the order of the columns to be returned with `*` is arbitrary, you cannot guarantee the columns coming back.

Comment: "cannot guarantee the columns coming back"?  i.e. something might prevent a column (or some records) from coming back on the join?

Comment: @Hardryv: The underlying schema can change as the database evolves.

Comment: Bad practice in also that some day you or someone else adds a BLOB or other large type to the table and suddenly you're returning 10MB of extra data

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can do this:

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.column FROM ...
```

I believe that it can be done in MYSQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.id
FROM foo
JOIN bar
ON …
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using JOIN you can use this syntax:

SELECT b.column_you_want, f.*
FROM foo f
INNER JOIN bar b
ON f.id=b.id

Note that b and f are nicknames of bar and foo, respectively.  INNER JOIN is the longer version of Alex Brasetvik's answer.  I used it because you specifically said you wanted to JOIN tables together.  It's also more versatile than the short form because you can use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN (more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).  You can also join multiple tables in multiple ways which is very useful if you need related data from many sources (tables).  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

can you try?

```
select f.id, b.* from foo f,bar b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*, y.specific 
FROM x 
JOIN y on x.id = y.id 
...
```